# Hey, i need to enter words to the list then count them an and print how many items in that list without counting duplicates

Tags: python-3.x

You are learning a new language, and are having a competition to see how many unique words you know in it to test your vocabulary learning.

Write a program where you can enter one word at a time, and be told how many unique words you have entered. You should not count duplicates. The program should stop asking for more words when you enter a blank line.

For example:

Word: Chat
Word: Chien
Word: Chat
Word: Escargot
Word: 
You know 3 unique word(s)!
​
and

Word: Katze
Word: Hund
Word: Maus
Word: Papagei
Word: Schlange
Word: 
You know 5 unique word(s)!

Comment: please let us know what u did and where you stuck. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sets and then take the length of the set like bellow:

```
len(set(your_list))
```